# Elasticsearch - Searching for multiple values in multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch

1. I'm trying to retrieve documents that have any of the values (France) OR (worldwide) OR (world wide) in any shipping_addr* fields but I need each document to be counted once even if there are several matches in document. Am I in right direction?
2. In general, what should I read/search for to understand the counting hits logic in case of several matches?

   ```
    GET /data/_search
    {
        "query": {
        "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
            "query_string": {
            "default_field": "shipping_addr*",
            "query": "(France) OR (worldwide) OR (world wide)"
            }
            }
        ]
        }
    }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) to understand how a particular search query is working and how some documents are matching or not matching.

Regarding your first point, I am not clear what exactly you want to achieve, you should always add some example to make it clear, but you can look at [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) which is used to solve the issue, and I guess you are looking for `should` clause which is equivalent to `OR`.

Instead of `query string` would suggest you use the boolean query which is less strict in syntax and advised in official docs

> If you don’t need to support a query syntax, consider using the match
> query. If you need the features of a query syntax, use the
> simple_query_string query, which is less strict.